# Nuget packages does not get install properly in freshly installed VS

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I have freshly install and update `VS Community version 16.10.0` in a freshly installed Windows 10.

Now I have created a small console app and added a unit test project both in `.Net Core 3.1 LTS`. After that nothing else is done. What I see is that nuget packages for test project is not properly installed although when you check in the `nuget package manager`, all the package are installed, all of those are installed.

Then I open an old application but the issue is same. Unit test packages are showing with error and same for EF core.

I tried to tweak/build etc. but non fixed the issue.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a try to restart the visual studio? And after installing, can you see warning or error messages in the output windows?

Comment: delete the packages folder and try restoring the `nuget` packages again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to missing `nuget` source link in `Package Source` under `NuGet Package Manager`.
As soon as I added the package source everything stated to work.

> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

The above source link suppose to already be added by default in `Package Source` but for some unknown reason it was missing. So whatever packages needed such as EFCore and MS Test framework etc. could not be downloaded, hence the problem was.